# Skip gradle configuration phase on submodules

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build, configuration

Lets suppose I have a gradle project:

```
/
submodule/
    build.gradle
anothermodule/
    build.gradle
build.gradle
```

If I enter `gradle build` it just builds all projects as expected.

But when I enter `gradle :submodule:build` besides building the submodule it also passes the configuration phase of `anothermodule`. When something goes wrong in the configuration of the other module, it aborts building `submodule`.

The only way I know to prevent from that, is to temporarily remove `anothermodule` from the `settings.gradle`, call `build` on `submodule` and reinsert it. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to omit the configuration phase of non related modules, or at least ignore errors in the config phase of `anothermodule` and proceed with what I told gradle to do (which is building `submodule`)?

Comment: See "configuration on demand" feature : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand

Comment: you should also consider using the new Configuration Avoidance API , see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html  and https://blog.gradle.org/preview-avoiding-task-configuration-time